# JDBC : Connect to Oracle DB through tnsname strange error

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I wrote a java program to synchronize two tables on two different remote databases.

The program works fine to connect to both databases if there isn't any special characters in the Username or Password, otherwise, it connects to the first DB successfully but failed on the second one.

Suppose my system property "oracle.net.tns_admin" is set correctly and the tnsname.ora file has no problem. I have three databases with tnsname, username, password like :

1. "TESTDB1","AAA","AAA!"
2. "TESTDB2","BBB","BBB!"
3. "TESTDB3","CCC",**"CCC"**  // no special character in password part.

   Here are my test cases and the return values for the program:

1> Test case 1: connect to two database 1 TO 2:

> ```
>  Source DB:[TESTDB1, AAA, AAA!]  Connect Successfully to source DB! 
>  Dest DB:[TESTDB2, BBB, BBB!]  Connect to dest DB failed!
> ```

2> Test case 2: connect to the same database twice:

> ```
>  Source DB:[TESTDB1, AAA, AAA!]  Connect Successfully to source DB! 
>  Dest DB:[TESTDB1, AAA, AAA!]  Connect to dest DB failed!
> ```

3> Test case 3: connect to two database 1 TO 3:

> ```
>  Source DB:[TESTDB1, AAA, AAA!]  Connect Successfully to source DB! 
>  Dest DB:[TESTDB3, CCC, CCC]   Connect Successfully to dest DB!
> ```

4> Test case 4: connect to two database 3 TO 1:

> ```
>  Source DB:[TESTDB3, CCC, CCC]   Connect Successfully to source DB! 
>  Dest DB:[TESTDB1, AAA, AAA!]  Connect to dest DB failed!
> ```

Only test case 3 successes. The failed message is :"ORA-01017:Invalid username/password;logon denied." for the failed connections.
So the wield part is why the program couldn't connect to the DB if there is a special character in username or password for the second database ? Can you try my program below and test out ?

Full code: (You must have oracle database and configure the "oracle.net.tns_admin" to your path of tnsname.ora file)

```
import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;
public class JDBCTest {
    public boolean success = false; 

    public JDBCTest() {
        System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "S:\\"); // Modify your path here
    }

    public static void debug(Object obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    } 
    public String processSync(String[] sourceConfig, String[] descConfig) {
        String vReturn = "Successfully copied the data from " + sourceConfig[0] + " to "
                + descConfig[0];
        String thinConn = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + sourceConfig[0];
        String username = sourceConfig[1];
        String password = sourceConfig[2];
        Connection conn1 = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
            debug("Source DB:"+Arrays.asList(sourceConfig));
            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(thinConn, username,
                    password);
            conn1.setAutoCommit(false);
            statement = conn1.createStatement();
            debug("Connect Successfully to source DB!");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            vReturn="Connect to source DB failed!"+"["+sqle.getMessage()+"]";
            debug("Connect to source DB failed!");
        }

        thinConn = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + descConfig[0].trim();
        password = descConfig[1].trim();
        username = descConfig[2].trim(); 
        Statement statement2 = null;
        Connection conn2 = null;
        try { 
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
            debug("Dest DB:"+Arrays.asList(descConfig));
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(thinConn, username,
                    password);
            conn2.setAutoCommit(false);
            statement2 = conn2.createStatement();
            debug("Connect Successfully to dest DB!");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            vReturn="Connect to dest DB failed!"+"["+sqle.getMessage()+"]";
            debug("Connect to dest DB failed!");
        }

        if (conn1 != null && conn2 != null) { 
            debug("Successfully connect to both Databases");
        }else{
            return vReturn;
        }
        success = true; 
        return vReturn; 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        JDBCTest newTest = new JDBCTest();  
    String[] sourceConfig={"TESTDB1","AAA","AAA!"};
    String[] descConfig={"TESTDB2","BBB","BBB!"}; //{"TESTDB3","CCC","CCC"};
        newTest.processSync(sourceConfig, descConfig);
    }

}
```

Comment: use diffrent connection thinConn and thinConn2 and try

Comment: Why are you using trim for 2nd database why not first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped username and password for conn2.

```
   password = descConfig[1].trim();
   username = descConfig[2].trim();
```

should be

```
  username = descConfig[1].trim();
  password = descConfig[2].trim();
```

Comment: OMG! How careless I am ! Thank you very much!